# How to link custom domain name to multi region api gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have created a hosted zone resource via  cloudformation. Now i want to create an api gateway via same template in two regions, say us-east-1 and us-west-1 .

```
customDomain:
  Type: AWS::Route53::HostedZone
  Properties:
     Name: 'example.com'
```

I understand , i will have to create ssl certificate in both regions. so i have created another stack below. but how do i link , my example.com to api gateway on both the regions.
the error i'm getting now , if i deploy the stack below to second region is - create failed for Mycustomdomainconfig => "The domain name you provided already exists. (service: ApiGateway, ...Status Code 400...

```
Resources: 
  MyCertificate: 
    Type: "AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate"
    Properties: 
      DomainName: example.com
      ValidationMethod: DNS
      DomainValidationOptions:
        - DomainName: 'example.com'
           HostedZoneId: 'abcde'

Myrecord:
  Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
  Properties:
    Region: !Ref aws_region
    SetIdentifier: !Sub "endpoint-${aws_region}"
    HostedZoneId:  'abcde'
    Name:  'example.com'
    Type: A
    AliasTarget:
      DNSname: !GetAtt  Mycustomdomainconfig.RegionalDomainName
      HostedZoneId: !GetAtt Mycustomdomainconfig.RegionalHostedZoneId
  
Mycustomdomainconfig:
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName
  Properties:
    RegionalCertificationArn: !Ref MyCertificate
    DomainName: 'example.com'
    ...

MyApiMapping:
   Type: AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping
   Properties:
     DomainName: !Ref Mycustomdomainconfig
     RestApiId: !Ref MyApi
     ...

MyApi:
   Type:  AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      ....
```